# Finding the best BigO notation with two strong terms

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am asked to find the simplest exact answer and the best big-O expression for the expression:

sum n, n = j to k.

I have computed what I think the simplest exact answer is as:

-1/2(j-k-1)(j+k)

Now when I go to take the best possible big-O expression I am stuck.

From my understanding, big-O is just finding the operation time of the worst case for an algorithm by taking the term that over powers the rest. So like I know:

n^2+n+1 = O(n^2)

Because in the long run, n^2 is the only term that matters for big n.

My confusion with the original formula in question:

-1/2(j-k-1)(j+k)

is as to what the strongest term is? To try and solve again I try factoring to get:

-1/2(j^2-jk-j+jk-k^2-k)

Which still does not make itself clear to me since we now have j^2-k^2. Is the answer I am looking for O(k^2) since k is the end point of my summation?

Any help thanks.

EDIT: It is unspecified as to which variable (j or k) is larger.

Comment: Side note (not exactly answering your question): For the series 1+2+3+4...+k, you can analytically solve the exact solution as (k*(k+1)) / 2. For the series j + (j+1) + (j+2) ... + k, you can do (k*(k+1))/ 2 - (j*(j+1))/2. It can be O(1) in this case. This series is called the triangle numbers, by the way.

Comment: Hmm so: sum n, n = j to k, is a triangular series? Is my solution of -1/2(j-k-1)(j+k) wrong then? 

I think I am confused as to how you got your solution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number Assuming I am interpreting your summation correctly.

Comment: I did not know you could establish a triangle numbers series without knowing the starting index?

Comment: I thought the starting index was `j` and the end was `k`?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, j is just an unknown variable, I thought you had to know the numeric value of the start, such as with the series 1+2+3+4+k where you know n = 0.

Comment: So long as `j` and `k` are numeric data types such that `j <= k`, the formula will work.

Comment: Okay, so then the elements in the series are basically represented as (j+k) added together. And we know that k will just be 1+2+3+4+k, leaving j, which can be also evaluated to (j(j+1))/2.

And since k is the end value and must be >= j, it is k-j or (k*(k+1))/ 2 - (j*(j+1))/2.

Am I following you correctly here?

Answer (score 0):

If you know `k > j`, then you have `O(k^2)`.  Intuitively, that's because as numbers get bigger, squares get farther apart.

It's a little unclear from your question which variable is the larger of the two, but I've assumed that it's `k`.

Comment: Yes this would make sense, however it is not specified if j > or < k.